# Head nodes of Linked lists not getting updated

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been implementing a simple **utility** function in Linked lists called ***MoveNode()*** using **Java**.

The main aim of **MoveNode()** is to remove the first node of one linked list (Source list) and add it to the beginning of another Linked list (Destination list).

Example is as follows:

```
Destination_Linked_List = {1,2,3} 
Source_List_List = {4,5,6}
```

After calling `MoveNode(Destination_Linked_List,Source_List_List)` we get:

```
Destination_Linked_List = {4,1,2,3}
Source_List_List = {5,6}
```

The following is my **Java** implementation of the above:

```
static void MoveNode(LinkedList LL1,LinkedList LL2)
{
    Node sourceref = LL2.head;
    Node destref = LL1.head;
    Node temp = sourceref.next;
    sourceref.next = destref;
    LL1.head = sourceref;
    LL2.head = temp;
}
```

***Works Perfectly!!***

But if I change the last two lines of my code and replace it with the local `Node` variables, the output changes completely.

Here it is:

If I change:

```
   LL1.head = sourceref;
   LL2.head = temp;
```

to:

```
   destref = sourceref;
   sourceref = temp;
```

The output which I get by performing this change is:

```
 Destination_Linked_List = {1,2,3} 
 Source_List_List = {4,1,2,3}
```

*What is the reason behind this **anomaly**? Why do the head nodes of the lists not get updated properly? What am I missing?*

P.S. - The *head* node is a global variable which can be accessed from any function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the head nodes of the lists does not get updated properly?

Because you're just changing the values of local variables. That's *all* you're doing - you're not making any changes to the list objects at all. Changes to local variables have no effect outside the method itself.

Note that when I say "changes to local variables" I mean something like:

```
localVariable = someOtherValue;
```

If instead you have:

```
localVariable.someMember = someOtherValue;
```

then that *might* have an effect outside the method, because that's changing the member of an object. If that object is accessible outside the method, then the change will be visible there too.

Comment: Alright! Got it. But can you please elaborate on how any changes made to the localVariable.someMember changes the actual value?

Comment: @Daggerhunt: It doesn't change the value of `localVariable` - it changes the information stored within the object that the value of `localVariable` refers to. That's the point - think of variables as pieces of paper. Suppose both a local variable and a variable somewhere else both have my home address on - like references to my house. If you navigate to my house using the local variable and then paint the door red, then someone who navigates to my house using a different piece of paper will also see a red door. But if you just change what's on your piece of paper, they wouldn't see *that*.

Comment: Excellent explanation.I now understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't change the head of the source list, is still points to the same first element, but that first element already points to the start of the destination list.

Therefore the destination list looks unchanged (since you didn't change its head) and the source list begins with the same head, but continues with the elements of the destination list.

```
LL1.head -> 1->2->3

            ^
            | 
LL2.head -> 4 5->6
```